# Converting a float to hh:mm format

Tags: python, date, python-3.x, time

I want to print a float value that I've got after performing some math as time string in the hh:mm format. Currently I have the float like 9.888888888888886 and I want it in time like 09:50. I have tried the following code:

```
    time = str(time)
    time = time.split(".")
    time[1] = float(time[1])
    time[1] *= 0.6
    time[1] = str(time[1])
```

and when I print I use

```
    str(time[0]) + ":" + time[1][:2]
```

Any way to achieve this effect consistently? With more advanced inputs my above code does not work properly, and outputs the wrong time.

Comment: Define "does not work properly". Define "wrong time".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Alternatively to using `datetime`, you can just use simple formatting with a bit of maths, eg:

```
result = '{0:02.0f}:{1:02.0f}'.format(*divmod(time * 60, 60))
```

(This assumes that `time` is nonnegative.)

Comment: what if you want to have it in the format HH:MM:SS?

Comment: It does not round correctly, `time=0.999` becomes `00:60` instead of `01:00`

Answer (score 15):

Using [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.timedelta(hours=9.888888888888886)
datetime.timedelta(0, 35600)
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(hours=9.888888888888886))
'9:53:20'
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(hours=9.888888888888886)).rsplit(':', 1)[0]
'9:53'
```

---

```
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time()) + \
... datetime.timedelta(hours=9.888888888888886)
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 16, 9, 53, 20)
>>> _.strftime('%H:%M')
'09:53'
```

Answer (score 9):

Using divmod you get the remainder and the quotient of a division.

```
minutes = 9.888888888888886*60
hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)

print "%02d:%02d"%(hours,minutes)
```

Output:

```
09:53
```

If you want the seconds too:

```
seconds = 9.888888888888886*60*60
minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)

print "%02d:%02d:%02d"%(hours,minutes,seconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

For python 3.7 version this becomes an one-liner.

```
x = 9.888888888888886

print (str(datetime.timedelta(hours=x))[:-3])
```

*(Here the time-string minus the last three chars is printed.)*

> Result 1 : 9:53

Alternatively if you needs seconds:

`print (datetime.timedelta(hours=x))`

> Result 2 : 9:53:20

And finally if you go beyond the 24hour mark timedelta shows the added day as well:

x = 39.888888888888886

> Result 3 : 1 day, 15:53:20

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to turn `9.888888888888886` into `09:53`, based on the former being floating point hours, and you don't want to worry about days, without a library you could simply do:

```
fhours = 9.888888888888886
ihours = int(ihours)
"%02d:%02d" % (ihours,(fhours-ihours)*60)
```

With only the math module, try

```
import math
"%02d:%02d" % (fhours,math.modf(fhours)[0]*60)
```

You might think that using the `datetime` module would help, but it's actually a bit fiddly. You can get a timedelta object out by passing in your fractional hours:

```
 import datetime
 td = datetime.timedelta(hours=9.888888888888886)
```

But getting that into a time object or a datetime object to format is the tricky bit, you end up having to do something like

```
 import datetime
 td = datetime.timedelta(hours=9.888888888888886)
 (datetime.datetime(2000,1,1)+td).strftime("%H:%M")
```

(That uses a randomly picked date to get the time delta into a datetime to use)