# How to convert a float number between 0 and 1 to hour time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I read a dataset that contains hours (i.e. 9:30 am) from a csv file. After exploring dataset, I saved it as a `.xlsx` format. Now, I want to add some fields to this dataset, however, hours data are in float numbers between 0 to 1.

In other example, I converted those numbers to `string` and it returned the hour. But with this format, this method just return float number in string format.

Consider this dataframe with an example of this data:

```
hours = [0.375, 0.41666666, 0.79166666, 0.79166666, 0.833333333, 0.375]
cities = ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AF', 'AG', 'AT']
df = pd.DataFrame({'hour': hours, 'city': cities})
```

I have tried to convert to datetime the hours field

```
df['hours'] = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in df['hour']]
```

However I got as a result:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

I was following this answer [Converting a float to hh:mm format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496889/converting-a-float-to-hhmm-format) but time format is different from what I have in dataset.

Is there an specific method I can use in `datetime` or in `pandas` to convert those numbers to hours?

Comment: Is each float a value in time of a 24-hour clock? Then `*24`. Is it a fraction of an hour? Then `*60` to get minutes. Basic clock math, really.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @usr2564301. each float is a value in time of a 24-hour clock. Now I can figure out how to convert those to actual time. Thanks