# How to convert float into Hours Minutes Seconds?

Tags: python, time, floating

I've values in float and I am trying to convert them into Hours:Min:Seconds but I've failed. I've followed the following post:

[Converting a float to hh:mm format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496889/converting-a-float-to-hhmm-format)

For example I've got a value in float format:

```
time=0.6 

result = '{0:02.0f}:{1:02.0f}'.format(*divmod(time * 60, 60))
```

and it gives me the output:

```
00:36
```

But actually it should be like "00:00:36". How do I get this?

Comment: Show an actual input with an expected output. Right now, the other question is completely irrelevant to what you want (although it is a good starting point). It is very unclear how you intend to format a float as HH:MM:SS.

Comment: There are many ways to convert, but they really depend on the *meaning* of the float value. The usual standard is that the value is the fraction of a day that the time is. But your example implies that the value is the fraction of a minute. Which is it, or is the meaning something else?

Comment: i ve given example as well

Comment: its the fraction of time. Like 0.6 means 36 seconds

Comment: You can check out my one-liner answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57018596/8928024) that gives you the 00:00:36 format without performing the regular expression string formatting yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divmod function accepts only two parameter hence you get either of the two
[Divmod()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)

So you can try doing this:

```
time = 0.6
mon, sec = divmod(time, 60)
hr, mon = divmod(mon, 60)
print "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hr, mon, sec)
```

Comment: Nice solution but I think using datetime as suggested by @weakit is the cleaner solution here.

Answer (score 9):

You can make use of the datetime module:

```
import datetime
time = 0.6
result = str(datetime.timedelta(minutes=time))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not obtaining the hours from anywhere so you'll first need to extract the hours, i.e.:

```
float_time = 0.6  # in minutes
hours, seconds = divmod(float_time * 60, 3600)  # split to hours and seconds
minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)  # split the seconds to minutes and seconds
```

Then you can deal with formatting, i.e.:

```
result = "{:02.0f}:{:02.0f}:{:02.0f}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
# 00:00:36
```